# "Console" output on Installation screen?

Tags: install4j

at the moment we use the Installation screen to display the installation progress and the currently running action (e.g. "Installing step 4").

As an additional information we would like to present the user informations, what happend before, e.g.:

Installed step 1 - ok

Installed step 2 - ok

Installed step 3 - ok

To do this we would need some kind of console (e.g. a text field / area) on the Installation screen below the progress bar. Is there a chance to do this?

Thanks!
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently that's not easily possible. You could extend `com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.InstallationScreen` and override the method `protected void addScreenContent(JPanel panel, GridBagConstraints gc)` to add more visual elements.

---

**Update:**

As Frank pointed out, you can just use a customizable form screen and add a "Progress display" component to it. In the "Post-activation script" property you would have to switch to the next screen automatically by calling

context.goForward(1, true, true);

Comment: Hi Ingo,

thanks for your reply. Could it be an alternative to use a standard screen instead of the Installation screen for running the installation process? The progress information could be displayed using the "Progress display" component.

regards!
Frank