# Set TextArea text dynamically by script

Tags: install4j

This a  follow-up question to [Console output on Installation screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068395/console-output-on-installation-screen)

I've configured a screen that contains a Text area component ("log.display") that should display what happened during my installation. The installation runs in a script that is attached to this screen. After finishing an installation step I do something like this (displayLog is initialized before):

```
    displayLog = displayLog + currentStep + " done. \n";
    context.setVariable("log.display",displayLog);
```

Unfortunatelly the Text area component is not updated by this. What can (must) I do to update the Text area dynamically from my script?

**EDIT:**

I found:

```
    formPanelContainer = (FormPanelContainer)context.getScreenById(<screenID>); 
    formPanelContainer.getFormEnvironment().reinitializeFormComponents();
```

this seems to work, but there is one problem with that: If the "log" displayed with this solution contains more lines than the Text area can display, it shows the vertical scrollbar but doesn't scroll to the last line automatically. Is there a way to let the Text area do that?

And another question: Is it possible to ask context for the current screen without specifying a screenID (what can change)?

thanks!
Frank

Answer (score 1):

The solution for my problem seems to be: get the ConfigurationObject of the TextArea component:

```
FormPanelContainer formPanelContainer = (FormPanelContainer)context.getScreenById(<ScreenID>);
FormEnvironment formEnvironment = formPanelContainer.getFormEnvironment();
FormComponent logComponent = formEnvironment.getFormComponentById(<TextAreaComponentID>);
JTextArea logComponentObject = (JTextArea)logComponent.getConfigurationObject();
```

and each time, something has to be logged:

```
logComponentObject.append("Text to log" + "\n");
logComponentObject.setCaretPosition(logComponentObject.getDocument().getLength());
```

This works fine in my setup.